# Display error when receiving IMEI in android studio

Tags: java, android, imei

I have an Android application.

But when I try to use IMEI, it shows an error message

this error :

> **The user 10379 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers.**

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
System.out.println("IMEI::" + telephonyManager.getDeviceId());
```

Comment: did you give permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

Comment: i set this permission  in manifest file ... but didn't work ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now a days android retrict the imei no and its providing the software no. You can try this, It will definitely solve your problem.

```
public static String getIMEINumber(Context context) {
    String deviceId;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(
                context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    } else {
        final TelephonyManager mTelephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (mTelephony.getDeviceId() != null) {
            deviceId = mTelephony.getDeviceId();
        } else {
            deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(
                    context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        }
    }
    return deviceId;
}
```

Comment: i used your code... but didn't show IMEI in Text view ...
min sdk : 17 max sdk = 29

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> this permission you have to add in you manifeast

Comment: yes , i have set this permission in manifest file ... but don't show text view ...

Comment: do you any desk in your system ?

Comment: yes . My problem was solved ... please remote to my system with any desk
838 151 476

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you. you can't get IMEI above API level 26. SO use deviceId.  This code is in Kotlin.

```
private fun telephonyService() {
    val telephonyManager = getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
    val imei = if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        print("Phone >= 26 IMEI")
        telephonyManager.imei
    } else {
        print("Phone IMEI < 26")
        telephonyManager.deviceId
    }

    print("Phone IMEI $imei")
}
```

Comment: are you checking in Android 10?

Comment: yes .
this error : The user 10379 does not meet the requirements to access device identifiers.
min sdk : 17
max sdk = 29

Comment: Android 10 as per security concern it will not provide the IMEI number.

Comment: What number do you suggest I set the largest sdk to get the IMEI